# Rank correlation with only incomplete pairwise comparisons?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ordinal-data, ranking, paired-data

I am studying the online ad ecosystem and would like to study the relationship between prices advertisers pay to show an ad and the preferences of users.

In particular, I have a set of observations where an individual says they preferred ad A to ad B or vice versa, and I know the prices paid for each ad. Overall, I want to be able to say whether or not the price predicts satisfaction. Is the trend in the data that "Users seem to prefer more expensive ads" or "Users seem to prefer less expensive ads" or "Price does not seem to predict user preference"

There are many users, all seeing distinct ads at different prices.

Is there a statistical test for data of this kind? One where I could test the hypothesis of there being no relation between price and preference?

I had looked at Kendall's Tau since I can view my data as having an easy to calculate number of concordant and discordant pairs, but I don't think I can just use the vanilla Kendall's Tau since I do not have two full rankings, only some number of concordant and discordant pairs.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at conjoint analysis - I think your dataset could be represented in that manner.

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon Thanks, this looks really promising